# Python2: How to parse a logfile that is held open in another process reliably?

Tags: python, file, logging

I'm trying to write a Python script that will parse a logfile produced by another daemon. This is being done on Linux. I want to be able to parse the log file reliably.

In other words, periodically, we run a script that reads the log file, line by line, and does something with each line. The logging script would need to see *every* line that may end up in the log file. It could run say once per minute via cron.

Here's the problem that I'm not sure exactly how to solve. Since the other process has a write handle to the file, it could write to the while at the *same time* that I am reading from the same log file.

Also, every so often we would want to clear this logfile so its size does not get out of control. But the process producing the log file has no way to clear the file other than regularly stopping, truncating or deleting the file, and then restarting. (I feel like logrotate has some method of doing this, but I don't know if logrotate depends on the daemon being aware, or if it's actually closing and restarting daemons, etc. Not to mention I don't want other logs rotated, just this one specific log; and I don't want this script to require other possible users to setup logrotate.)

Here's the problems:

1. Since the logger process could write to the file while I already have an open file handle, I feel like I could easily miss records in the log file.
2. If the logger process were to decide to stop, clear the log file, and restart, and the log analyzer didn't run at exactly the same time, log entries would be lost. Similarly, if the log analyzer causes the logger to stop logging while it analyzes, information could also be lost that is dropped because the logger daemon isn't listening.
3. If I were to use a method like "note the size of the file since last time and seek there if the file is larger", then what would happen if, for some reason, between runs, the logger reset the logfile, but then had reason to log even more than it contained last time? E.g. We execute a log analyze loop. We get 50 log entries, so we set a mark that we have read 50 entries. Next time we run, we see 60 entries. But, all 60 are brand new; the file had been cleared and restarted since the last log run. Instead we end up seeking to entry 51 and missing 50 entries! Either way it doesn't solve the problem of needing to periodically clear the log.

I have no control over the logger daemon. (Imagine we're talking about something like syslog here. It's not syslog but same idea - a process that is pretty critical holds a logfile open.) So I have no way to change its logging method. It starts at init time, opens a log file, and writes to it. We want to be able to clear that logfile AND analyze it, making sure we get every log entry through the Python script at some point.

The ideal scenario would be this:

1. The log daemon runs at system init.
2. Via cron, the Python log analyzer runs once per minute (or once per 5 minutes or whatever is deemed appropriate)
3. The log analyzer collects every single line from the current log file and immediately truncates it, causing the log file to be blanked out. Python maintains the original contents in a list.
4. The logger then continues to go about its business, with the now blank file. In the mean time, Python can continue to parse the entries at its leisure from the Python list in memory.

I've very, very vaguely studied fifo's, but am not sure if that would be appropriate. In that scenario the log analyzer would run as a daemon itself, while the original logger writes to a FIFO. I have very little knowledge in this area however and don't know if it'd be a solution or not.

So I guess the question really is twofold:

1. How to reliably read EVERY entry written to the log from Python? Including if the log grows, is reset, etc.
2. How, if possible to truncate a file that has an open write handle? (Ideally, this would be something I could do from Python; I could do something like `logfile.readlines(); logfile.truncate` so that way no entries would get lost. But this seems like unless the logger process was well aware of this, it'd end up causing more problems than it solves.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see any particular reason why you should be not able to read log file created by syslogd. You are saying that you are using some process similar to syslog, and process is keeping your log file open? Since you are asking rather for ideas, I would recommend you to use syslog! http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc1%2Fhsyslog.html

It is working anyway – use it. Some easy way to write to log is to use logger command:

```
logger “MYAP: hello”
```

In python script you can do it like:

```
import os
os.system(‘logger “MYAP: hello”’)
```

Also remember you can actually configure syslogd. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc1%2Fconstmt.html

Also about your problem with empty logs – sysclog is not clearing logs. There are other tools for it – on debian for example logrotate is used. In this scenario if your log is empty – you can check backup file created by logrotate.

Since it looks like your problem is in logging tool, my advise would be to use syslog for logging. And other tool for rotating logs. Then you can easily parse logs. And if by any means (I don’t know if it is even possible with syslog) you miss some data – remember you will get it in next iteration anyway ;)

Some other idea would be to copy your logfile and work with copy...

Comment: I'm revisiting this question years later, but it's come up again :-) The problem is that the process doing the logging is not something I've written. The app simply opens a logfile and writes to it as it runs. I can't change that behavior. It's also not acceptable to regularly kill and restart that process. The idea would be if I could open the file in Python, read the contents, then *truncate* the file and *move its file pointer to 0*, so the application doing the logging would just start writing new entries to the beginning. Maybe that's not possible at all, but that's what I'd like.